# Can the values of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` be assumed to be constant?

Tags: c, stdio

From Ubuntu man page `stdin(3)`:

```
extern FILE *stdout;
```

From mingw64 `stdio.h` file:

```
#define stdout (&__iob_func()[1])
```

Both suggest that the value of `stdout` (a pointer) can not be assumed to be constant.

Can I still rely on something like this to work:

```
FILE * stream;

// early after startup
stream = stdout;

// much later, far down the stack, in a different function
fprintf(stream, "%s", "fprintf(stream, \"");
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve with code like in your example? Why do you ask? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: footnote 272) _The primary use of the freopen function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream
(stderr, stdin, or stdout), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value
returned by the fopen function may be assigned._

Comment: For all practical purposes yes. They are streams associated with the `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` (`0, 1, 2`). Having said that, they can be `dup()` and `dup2()`, and reassigned. Absent duping or reassigning, etc.. then the constants, and the associated streams are constant. Meaning, unless you have reassigned, etc., you can read from file descriptor `0` and write to file descriptors `1 & 2` and that will always be `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` -- unless you change them.

Comment: There is a thing called redirection. So after the second line, if some program or the computer user redirects stdout to somewhere else, your third line output would still print to the previous stdout. e.g. originally stdout is terminal. later it is redirected to a file (some log file). then fprintf will print to terminal instead of the log file.

Comment: @BLUEPIX Yes, in mingw64 it is a macro that expands to an rvalue expression. The question is: Will that expression be always the same value?

Comment: It may not always be the same value.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I get the idea, but `STDIN_FILENO`, `dup`, etc. are Unix, and I need a C standard answer (also valid for mingw etc.).

Comment: @Zhigang An Are you sure redirection can be done from outside? I thought it can be done by the process itself only. (A shell does fork, then redirect, then execve.)

Comment: @not-a-user redirection can be done by other processes if they have appropriate permissions. Think of gdb. You can change the output and input streams mid execution. Point being, it is not always safe to assume that they won't change. Infact the original pointer *may* also get deallocated.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I want to set a global variable, such that other functions know where to fprintf to. The value of `stdout` is used as a handle. I want to know if the handle remains valid for ever. (In comparison, a function pointer remains valid for ever. At least if you do not `dlclose()` it out of memory.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the C11 standard has to say (**§7.21.1-3**) (accent my own):

> stderr
>      stdin
>      stdout
>  
>   which are expressions of type ‘‘**pointer to FILE**’’ that point to the FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard
>   error, input, and output streams.